# Looping through a list of elemts to see if they are active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of elements (`<li>`), that have two particular `<li>` that share a class (`.example`) and I want to check that when any of this elements is active (having class `.active`) a pop-up should appear.

On the click event that toggles the class .active I added a loop to check if any of the `<li>` elements had this two classes but I can't seem to make it properly work.

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    $("ul li").each(function() {
      if($(this).hasClass('example') && $(this).hasClass('active')){
          $('.pop-up').css("display", "block")
        } else {
          $('.pop-up').css("display", "none")
      }
    })
  });
```

If one or both of the elements has the classes .example and .active the pop-up should appear.

Comment: Can you please include some HTML? I'm a bit unclear as to your request. I feel like this can be accomplished using a combined selector and `.length` without the need for loops. E.g., `if ( $("li.example.active").length )` will return `true` if there are any `<li>` elements that have both class `example` and class `active`.

Comment: Is a standard ul li structure, with five <li> in which the first two have the class example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below acts as you would like.

**Problem** - 
I think the issue with your code is that by definition some of your elements lack the classes `.example` and `.active`, so in the case of you activating an example it would show the modal, but hide it again as it cycled through all the other list items.

**Method One** - adapts your code and makes it a little more efficient, checking for the existence of an `li` with both classes `.active.example`

**Method Two** - is a little quicker as it just assumes that any click on a `li.example` element should show the pop-up (this is probably the user experience you're expecting, as the pop-up is unlikely to be closed through the process of clicking on the `li`, but rather through its own close button or similar)

As mentioned by @Hackbyrd - you may want to place the event listeners on a parent DOM element is you are dynamically loading these `li` elements (i.e. they are not present when the page loads).

I've added some styling to help tell what is going on. `.active` elements are underlined.

Let me know if this isn't what you were hoping for.

---

## Demo

```js
// METHOD ONE
// Add click event to list items
$('ul li').click(function() {

  // Add active class to clicked list element
  $(this).toggleClass('active');

  // Check if .example.active exists
  // i.e. length of array is greater than 0
  if ($("ul li.example.active").length > 0) {
    $('.pop-up').css("display", "block")
  } else {
    $('.pop-up').css("display", "none")
  }

});


// METHOD TWO
// Add click event to second example
$('ul li.example2').click(function() {

  // Show pop-up
  // This assumes that .active class is not needed for any other reason
  // And that the modal is closed via a different method (i.e. a close button within the modal, which is typical for a modal)
  $('.pop-up').show();

});


// Shouldn't be necessary, your modal should have a closing method already
// Only for demo purposes
$("a.close-pop-up").click(function() {
  $('.pop-up').hide();
});
```

```css
.pop-up {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.example {
  color: blue;
}

.example2 {
  color: green;
}

li.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Not an example list item</li>
  <li class="example">An example list item</li>
  <li class="example2">An example list item - METHOD 2</li>
  <li class="example">An example list item</li>
  <li class="example2">An example list item - METHOD 2</li>
  <li>Not an example list item</li>
</ul>

<div class="pop-up">
  <p>Pop-up</p>
  <a class="close-pop-up">Close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked! Damn I feel so dumb, thank you so much !

Comment: Glad it helped, we've all been there!

Answer (score 0):

Another issue you could be having is that the ul and li elements were loaded into the DOM dynamically (means it was loaded not when the page was loaded but through other various events).

**If this is the case you need to choose a higher parent element in the tree to attach the event listener too**.

Also, just like previous comments and answers, you can significantly shorten your code but instead attach it to the document (or a parent element was that loaded into the page on the page load, I chose document because I can see your HTML code) so that it does not make a difference if you loaded it dynamically or not.

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul li .example .active', function(e){ $('.pop-up').show(); })
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Also use this method

```js
showPopUp();

$('ul li.example').click(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $('ul li').removeClass('active');
  }else {
    $('ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
  
  showPopUp();
});

function showPopUp() {
  if($('ul li.example.active').length > 0) {
    $('.pop-up').show();
  }else {
    $('.pop-up').hide();
  }
}
```

```css
.example {
  color: #808080;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.example.active {
  color: #222222;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.pop-up {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li class="example">Test Example</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
  <li class="example">Test 2 Example</li>
</ul>

<p class="pop-up">This is a Pop Up</p>
```